# LDAP - filter on input data

Tags: ldap

This is a dirty workaround and very bad from architectural point of view, I know. Given two databases behind one LDAP server, trying to filter data based on user input and request **Case #1** from one directory and **Case #2** from another directory.

**Case #1** - user inputs email: email@mail.com
`(mail=${username})`
`(!(sAMAcountName=*))`

**Case #2** - user inputs login: usrlogin
`(!(mail=${username}))`
`(sAMAcountName=${username})`

My goal is to query data only from one of the cases above. So it's basically XOR operation of C1 and C2.

My attempt to write a query:
`(|(&(mail=email@mail.com)(!(sAMAcountName=*)))(&(!(mail=usrlogin))(sAMAcountName=usrlogin)))`

Comment: `(&(|(term1)(term2))(!(&(term1)(term2))))` this is XOR filter for LDAP query

Comment: Trying `(&(|(&(mail=a@b.c)(!(sAMAcountName=*)))(&(!(mail=usrlogin))(sAMAcountName=usrlogin)))(!(&(&(mail=a@b.c)(!(sAMAcountName=*)))(&(!(mail=usrlogin))(sAMAcountName=usrlogin)))))`, but without success. Timeout.

Comment: No one knows? :)